# How to add the tableview record/row into sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios

Here I insert the record statically into database.
My problem is that I want to add the recode from the tableview into sqlitedatabase.

```
-(IBAction)favouriteButtonClick
{
    NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [dirArray objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favouritecontact"];
    NSLog(@"Database path=>%@",databasePath);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO favourite(FirstName,LastName,FullName,HomeEmail,HomeEmail,WorkEmail,MobileNo)VALUES(\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\")",FirstName.text,LastName.text,FullName.text,HomeEmail.text,WorkEmail.text,MobileNo.text];

         NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO favourite(FirstName,LastName,FullName,HomeEmail,WorkEmail,MobileNo)VALUES('ketan','yadav','ketanyadav', 'ky@gmail.com','ketanyadav@gmail.com','1122334455')"];

         NSLog(@"insertsql%@",insertSQL);

         const char *insert_stmt=[insertSQL UTF8String];

         sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
         sqlite3_step(statement);
         sqlite3_finalize(statement);
         sqlite3_close(contactDB);
         NSLog(@"Record add to database");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the favourite button? Is it an accessory view in the tableView cell?

Comment: no. it is the rightbuttonitem button in navigationbaritem controller.

//here is the code

//when even i click on this button at that time i want to add the particular tableview recode into database.

UIBarButtonItem *favourite=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add TO Favourites" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(favouriteButtonClick)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=favourite;

Comment: i am use three view controller
in first view tableview in which contacts display
when even i click on perticular contact at that time second view call
then second view in which favourite button in navigation item rightbuttonitem i use when ever clik on it at that time perticular contact record save into database.

Comment: Ok. So what's the problem? It sounds like you've already got the data you need for the SQL database in that second view.

Answer (score 0):

you can find answer at below link:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

Here in this Example, there is a TextField, so it Saves Textfield's data, In your case you have to set value of your particular cell [of particular field]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to identify the currently selected row in the TableView when the user taps the 'favourite' button. Is that right?

This will give you the index of the current selection:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

If there's just one section in your TableView then `[selectedIndexPath row]` will give you the row number to look up in the array of contacts -- or whatever your data source is.